# arcanist: arc diff takes a lot of time to complete compared to svn diff

Tags: svn, phabricator, arcanist

I would like to use arcanist to send a differential of the local (uncommitted) changes in my SVN project (thousands of files) to Phabricator for review.

The problem is, when executing `arc diff` arcanist seems to go through every single file calling `svn diff` and `svn info`. As a result it takes like 5 minutes to complete. In comparison, running `svn diff` in the same directory lists all my local changes almost instantly.

Why does arcanist have this behavior? Would it be possible to just run `arc diff` with `svn diff` instead of a per-file info & diff?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A cleanup of the repo seemed to have solved all of my problems. Now it works as expected.